# Generate and reserve consecutive serial numbers

Tags: php, mysql, rest, mariadb

I'm facing a problem on how to reserve unique consecutive serials in a table of devices in a distributed environment.

*Situation*

The customer has multiple flashing stations, where devices are flashed.
According to the type of device, a consecutive serial number needs to be reserved, flashed onto the device and on successful flashing process confirmed to the DB.
I have to ensure the serial numbers are consecutive, even if the flashing process fails.
The serials are requested via a REST service by the flashing terminal.

*Current Solution*

In my current solution the flashing station requests a serial by device type.
The entry is created and marked "in progress". My problem is, if the software e.g. crashes, the serial number remain reserved and in worst case lead to gap in the serial numbers for the device type.
On success the status is set to "done" - that's the best case

my current table has the following columns : device type, serial, status, prod date

Any hint on a feasible approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: If the likelihood of a gap being left is quite small - using your example if the software crashes for some reason - can't you have a routine that would be run to "free up" the unused serial number, and have the "next new number" routine look for any abandoned ones. Sure, that'll mean it's out of sequence, but I don't see any way around that unless you're prepared to halt all production any time the process crashes.

Comment: The software crash is actually the most severe failure.
It starts with a rather basic problem. 
If I have 4 stations flashing the same device type, all 4 need to receive unique serials. If the flashing fails on one station, this station needs to keep the serial while the others need to get new unique serials.
Maybe I don't see the solution to this as I'm digging into this for 6 consecutive days and went down into a brain dead end...

Comment: _"My problem is, if the software e.g. crashes, the serial number remain reserved"_ and _"If the flashing fails on one station, this station needs to keep the serial"_ appear to contradict each other? I can currently not tell, what behavior you actually want/need, based on what you said so far.

Comment: I mean if the station crashes, I would reserve a new serial, this again results in a gap in the serial numbers.
If the flashing fails, I need to get the same serial, which was reserved before.

Comment: I don't know how long this flashing process takes. but there are several approaches. E.g. Before getting a serial number, check whether there is still a reserved number for the device type. For this purpose, you should add a column in the table indicating when (timestamp) this was reserved. If there is still one reserved and a timeout, now() - timestamp, you can handle it programmatically and, if necessary, release it again.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to REST? Would it work any different when using any other access?

Comment: It is not directly related to REST. I just wanted to point out which technologies I'm using. Basically this is a data storage / management problem.$

Comment: @BerndBuffen I will try this approach. Thanks for pointing me the direction to take. I was going down a dead end on this...

Comment: If this is not related to REST, please remove that tag

Comment: @MPH How is the flashing process related to the serial number? What are you doing with the serial number? Can you use/assign the serial number *after* the flashing is done?

Comment: "unique consecutive serials" -- How many at a time?

Comment: If something fails, do you want the numbers to be re-assigned?  Does there need to be any connection between on set of serials and another?

Comment: What should happen if you assign batches A,B,C, and D simultaneously but batch B fails _after_ batches C and D have been assigned?  Does this imply that the assignment _cannot_ be done in parallel -- that is, each batch must be assigned and used _or_ fail and the numbers reused _before_ moving on??

Comment: "serial number" -- Is the Serial number stored in the device?  If so, rephrase your Question with that requirement in mind.

Comment: If the "batches" are always of the same size -- that is, all numbers in the batch are used or all fail -- I see a simple solution.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, we may use the following method

Apart from the device table (which store the device type, serial, status, timestamp), create another table known as "release_pool"

**Under Current situation** - for a new job:

1. The device will get the "current maximum serial number" (e.g. maximum serial =10111)
2. The device db table will have a new record inserted as "serial=10112, device_name, timestamp, status=in progress"
3. When the device has finally flashed successfully, it is fine (update the db record status to "successful"). However, if it fails (crashes), then there will be "skipped serial number"

We may define a case to be "failed /crashed" when say after a reasonable time - say 5 minutes), it is still with status = "in progress"

Now, add the following step:

Whenever a device record is inserted, insert a db record in the "release_pool" with the same serial number (say "10112") and store the "timestamp"

Now, use the following **AMENDED WAY** for new job

1. The device will get the "next serial number"

   - first, look at the release_pool, if the timestamp indicates that it is failed (say after 5 minutes but not yet removed), use (i.e. re-use) this old serial number (at the same time mark the previous device table record status from "in progress" to "crashed")
   - if there is no record in the release_pool, then use the maximum serial number to derive the serial number
     (e.g. maximum serial =10111, it will use 10112)
2. The db table will have a record inserted as "serial=10112, device_name, timestamp, status=in progress"
3. At the same time, insert a db record in the "release_pool" with the serial number "10112" and store the "timestamp"
4. the device will perform the flashing, if it is successful - fine (update the status to "successful" and remove the record from the release_pool db table), but say if it is "not successful" , However, say after a reasonable time - say 5 minutes), then it is regarded as "crashed" / "failed"

So the method is

- use a temp table (release_pool) to store the jobs under progress
- if a job is successful, remove it from the release_pool
- if a job is crashed for a long time , the serial number will be re-used when a new job is started

**Performance-wise**, a temp, small table (release_pool) is a better choice than simply look at the device table to find out which records are failed based on timestamp